# Complicated conditional probability problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am attempting to solve the following probability problem but am having trouble conceptualizing the solution. I found one similar inquiry here ([Complicated probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835956/complicated-probability-question)) but was unable to successfully apply it to my situation.

I have 9 university courses, each of which can be registered for by 0 to 20 students. Each of 25 university students must select 3 of the 9 courses to register in.

Notes - Once a course fills (reaches registration of 20 students) it is effectively closed and can no longer be registered for. From that point, students have one less course from which to select. (e.g. If one course fills, students subsequently have only 8 courses (9-1) to choose from.)

I'm trying to figure out the probability that each of the 9 courses will be registered for by 5 or more students.

I understand that the number of possible registration choices for each student is 84 (9!/3!(9-3))...but I'm not even sure if that is relevant given the problem I am attempting to solve. I also understand that the sum total of registrants needs to be 75 (25x3) if my registration rules are strict (each student must register for 3 courses, no more/no less) but cannot figure out where this should be used either.

I would be most appreciative of any advice that pushes me in the correct direction.

Comment: I would googling Stirling numbers, since they are definitely involved in the solution.

Comment: You should clarify one aspect of this good problem:  Suppose one class is filled with $20$ students and student number $21$ wants to attend that class (but cannot).  Is student $21$ routed to the current *least filled* class?  ... or to a randomly chosen class from the remaining $8$?  And what happens in the (rare) case of two classes being full?  Or three?  (There can never be four...)

Comment: The number of registration choices for a given student is (at most) $(9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7)/3! = 84$.  But in rare cases the student will be prevented from registering for a (full) class.

Comment: David, thank you for the comment here. Yes, the maximum enrollment for a class is 20. Thus once one course reaches maximum enrollment, it is effectively closed and students subsequently have only 8 choices instead of 9. I am looking at the problem from a mathematical perspective (from the perspective of each individual course) and trying to calculate the probability that each of the 9 courses ends up with an enrollment of 5 students or more (all other circumstances (e.g. course title, instructor, time slot, etc.) being ignored).

Comment: @JasonHollowell:  I too tried the approach you mention, stating that each class had a $1/3$ chance any given student would enroll, but that (using a binomial distribution) gives you only an *approximate* answer.  The real tricky part is the "full class" condition, which ruins all the otherwise-lovely binomial results.  If class sizes were $25$ (hence never an over full class), then the problem is fairly straightforward....

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Sorry, I just realized I did not reply to one of your inquiries here. When a course is full (20 students) students who wish to join that course are randomly assigned (they chose) a different course from the remaining courses (8 or less). Thanks again for your input here.

Comment: Please add this rule (along with an earlier clarification) into the body of the question, instead of commenting. Please click on the tiny `edit` button and improve the post.

Answer (score 1):

A *partial* answer (or hint):

Consider a specific class.  Each student has a 3/9 = 1/3 chance of registering for it.  Hence (naively) the number of students in the class will follow a binomial distribution of $25$ students, each having chance $1/3$ of registering:

[image]

One can then easily calculate the probability the number of the students in the class is $5$ or more ($p = 0.953799$).  And then you can easily calculate the probability that *all* classes have at least $5$ students ($p^{25}=0.6533$).

*BUT* this is not the correct answer, for two reasons.

- The binomial distribution is defined for up to $25$ students in a class, but that is explicitly precluded by the class limit of $20$.  Thus the above approach is incorrect.
- The above calculation and distribution (plot) might hold for the first class under consideration, but the probabilities change for each successive class, given the "conservation of total number of students."

Nevertheless... it is an approximation... a start!

Comment: David, thanks a million. This definitely gets me going in the right direction. It is already above my ability level but hopefully within reach if I spend a bit of time with it. How to get to something that approaches my final goal may be much further off. ;-)